# Data hub framework version upgrade to latest supported version from 2.0.6 to 4.3.1

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am upgrading to Data hub framework 4.3.1 from 2.0.6 on MarkLogic server 9.0-6.2 (localhost). Build got successful using mlDeploy but at the same time i am encountering an issue:

```
Error occurred while loading modules; host: localhost; port: 8010; cause: Local message: /config/query write failed: Bad Request. Server Message: RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT: (err:FOER0000) Invalid content: invalid paths to extract document data: //*:instance/(TestA|TestB|TestC - archive|TestD)
com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: /config/query write failed: Bad Request. Server Message: RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT: (err:FOER0000) Invalid content: invalid paths to extract document data: //*:instance/(TestA|TestB|TestC - archive|TestD)
       at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.putPostValueImpl(OkHttpServices.java:2847)
       at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.putValue(OkHttpServices.java:2704)
       at com.marklogic.client.impl.QueryOptionsManagerImpl.writeOptions(QueryOptionsManagerImpl.java:158)
       at com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultModulesLoader.lambda$installQueryOptions$3(DefaultModulesLoader.java:546)
       at com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultModulesLoader.lambda$executeTask$5(DefaultModulesLoader.java:583)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 25s
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
```

NOTE: TestA, TestB, TestC - archive, TestD are the entities (I have mocked up these entities. Actual production name for entities is different but format is same).

Even I have deleted "TestC - archive" entity folder and rename it to "TestCArchive", redeploy but "TestCArhive" entity is not mentioned in error whereas I can see old entity name which is "TestC - archive".

Also, in the module database, I can see new entity only which is "TestCArchive". Nowhere, this new version providing entity validation and I am strange with this.

Answer (score 0):

"TestC - archive" is an invalid path. Perhaps this is the entity name but not what it's called in the XML/JSON. You can try a complete redeploy of the data hub and/or clear out all the databases and redeploy.